# Silent / quiet luggage, trolley, on wheels

Tags: luggage

I am looking for luggage with quiet wheels. That means that even if I am walking on a below average quality European sidewalk with lots of small gaps between the cobblestones pulling the trolley after midnight through an empty street doesn't annoy the people living on the ground level of that street.

This is a very demanding requirement. But humans are inventive and there should be a market for it. Google wasn't of much help.

I am willing to trade off extra friction for reduced noise. Air filled wheels sound like a good idea to me. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I dare say it's impossible to manufacture such a suitcase unless the wheels are extremely large.

Comment: Buy a backpack.

Comment: @gerrit ...and break your back.

Comment: @gdrt It's the only quiet solution, and it's arguably hard to make a properly built cabin-size equivalent backpack heavy enough to break the back.  A good backpack puts weight on the hips, not on the shoulders.

Comment: @gerrit, interesting insights, but bear in mind that not all people are strong.

Comment: @gdrt as opposed to [breaking your mother's back](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72185/step-on-a-crack-break-your-mother-s-back).

Comment: @gdrt I disagree that you have to be strong. You just have to not be VERY VERY weak. A relatively weak person should have no problem with a 15-20 pound backpack (the weight of my travel backpack), if it is designed properly.

Comment: @Thomas, where in the question did you see 15-20 pounds? My checked-in luggage usually weights 50 pounds and hell I'm not carrying it on my back for sure.

Comment: This feels strongly like a question created for advertising something.

Comment: @gdrt Huh. Many years ago (in my late 20s or early 30s) I walked the Milford Track in NZ carrying 50 kg in my backpack (camping gear plus food/booze for 4 days plus stove + fuel + cameras plus ...)

Comment: Good job @DavidPostill!

Comment: I have seen people using a separate foldable two wheel trolley, with quite big wheels, under their suitcase. Just select the trolley that is suitable for your ground. (And yes, I agree that better wheels are needed on luggage, my nearest railway station is 20 minutes walking and getting taxis for an early morning departure proves almost impossible.)

Answer (score 19):

This looks like what you're looking for:
[g-ro](https://g-ro.com/collections/shop-all).

[g-ro wheels](https://g-ro.com/pages/g-ro-wheels)

> Rolls easier: G-RO glides easily over many types of
>   surfaces—cobblestones, curbs, steps, gravel, snow, sand.

[image]

Comment: The OP talks about non-smooth surfaces.

Comment: @Henrik Indeed. And it performs better on *any terrain*, besides gliding on smooth surfaces too

Comment: Very hard to tell the scale from that picture.  Looks like airplane cabin size suitcase?

Comment: @gerrit It claims to be 22 inch tall cabin luggage size

Comment: rolls easier, but silent ?

Comment: Or get any 2-wheel cart at (whatever the local language word is for Walmart or Home Depot).

Comment: @gerrit it might be a bit had to pull around if it's the size of an airplane cabin!

Comment: @Harper, that'd be LOUDER than normal luggage though.

Comment: The website linked says *The "signature" G-RO sound: The "HUM" of our wheels was designed and inspired by the sound of sports cars and their special gears*. Nice design but not silent.

Comment: Looks wonderful, but 449 USD. :-(

Answer (score 7):

I selected luggage on a slightly different but related criterion: I wanted a suitcase with wheels that survive the real world.  Most suitcase wheels appear to be designed for airport lounges only, presumably on the assumption that you'd use a car or taxi to get to the airport and not walk your suitcase for 20 minutes on the street of Brussels.

Based on reading online reviews, I bought an [Eagle Creek suitcase](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00BYFCKEE/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00).  The wheels are roller blade wheels and it rolls easily on any surface.  Now, it's not perfectly silent on cobblestone, as I think nothing would be, but it's certainly better than your typical Samsonite or Antler.

[image: Eagle Creek]
Photo from Amazon.

Answer (score 6):

In theory there's no problem in manufacturing such luggage.

Physics tells that the required size of the wheels depend on how far below average quality sidewalks is supposed to be handled. Based on my guess they wouldn't neccessarily have to be extremely larger, 1.5-2 times the wheels typicaly seen on luggage, would probably go a long way.

But you'll probably also need the wheels mounted in a way that gives other parts of the luggage good ground clearance (unlike the one Berwyn shows in his answer), but then you also need some mechanism to move the wheels to a more retracted position so the luggage doesn't take up so much space when stored/stowed.

I've never seen such luggage, and I doubt many people would be interested in giving up that much space inside the luggage to fit larger wheels outside, so if it exists, it might be quite hard to find.